# Can't manage to return 100 results in Python

Tags: python, mysql, flask

So I'm trying to get 100 results from a MySQL database via Python. Here's what I got so far

```
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT author, quote FROM Quotes ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 100")

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    quote = row[1]
    author = row[0]

    return jsonify(quote=quote, author=author)
```

When I give this a run, I only get one result, like so

```
{
  "author": "Helen Keller",
  "quote": "Faith is the strength by which a shattered world shall emerge into the light."
}
```

I'm trying to return all 100, not just one quote. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you think `return` does, exactly?

Comment: It returns something?... @MathiasEttinger

Comment: Return essentially acts like a `break` after "returning" the first instance.change `return` to `print` . If you want to use the data outside the function, read it into a dictionary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning on your first pass through the `for` loop. That is why you only get one result.

Instead of the loop, you do something like this:

```
def testdb():
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT author, quote FROM Quotes ORDER BY RAND()")
    return jsonify(data=cursor.fetchall())
```

---

You will remove the `for` loop before your `return` statement. If you have `fetchall()` in there twice, without a second query, the second attempt will produce an empty list.

Comment: @Idris, see my update. You need to remove the entire `for` loop. You are utilizing `fetchall()` twice. After the first `fetchall()` there is nothing left to fetch, so the `return` statement was returning an empty list. If use `fetchall()` again, you'd need to run another query.

Comment: I got this to work earlier today, the only reason I didn't use it is because it doesn't return the "titles" before the string. All I get is the raw data, is there anyway to build the string to like the JSON example in my post?

Comment: @Idris change your query, then, to retrieve the data in the order you want. `SELECT author, quote` should become `SELECT quote, author` if order matters to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `return` statement is inside the `for` loop.

Comment: When I remove the indentation for the `return` I end up getting `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`

Comment: A possible solution would be using `yield`.

Comment: Could you show me an example? I'm new to Python @TidB

Comment: @Idris You might want to take a look at the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html%23generator-expressions) or google 'Python generators'.